# Apply two greps and awk to same input

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm using two short UNIX commands in my python script to get some data about nearby wireless access points.

- n°1, gets the ESSID of the access point :

`"iwlist NIC scan | grep ESSID | awk '{print $1}'"`

- n°2, gets the signal strength of the access point :

`"iwlist NIC scan | grep level | awk '{print $3}'"`

My problem is that I use these two commands one after the other which means that it doesn't generate "symmetric" data. You might get 6 ESSIDs and 4 Signal strength data.

Because the first time, the script found 6 APs (A, B, C, D, E and F) and the next time only 4 APs (A, C, E and F).

Some my question is the following :

- Is there a way to "split" the result of the first `iwlist NIC scan` and then apply two different `grep` and `awk` sequences to the same input ?

Just so that you at least get a symmetric list of results.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: I'd first execute the `iwlist` command and save it to a temp file and then run the `grep` + `awk` commands on that file. you can delete the file once you get the required output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
iwlist <NIC> scan > tmpfile
grep -i ESSID tmpfile | awk '{print $1}'
grep -i level tmpfile | awk '{print $3}'
rm tmpfile
```

A script something like this might just do what you're expecting.

Comment: Hum, yes this seems to be a good idea. I might do this. Thank you a lot for your quick answer !

Comment: Don't forget to ensure that the temp file is uniquely named (at least include `$$` in the name, to include the shell's PID), and also to clean up if the shell is signalled (use: `tmp=tmpfile.$$; trap "rm -f $tmp; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15; ...code as above...; rm $tmp; trap 0`.  The `trap 0` at the end cancels the trap on exit, allowing the script to exit successfully.

Answer (score 10):

What about using `awk` as `grep`:

```
iwlist NIC scan | awk '/ESSID/ {print $1} /level/ {print $3}'
```

This gives you the ESSID and level lines all at once.  You'd probably want to be a little more sophisticated and at least tag the lines with what it represents; the options are legion.  It isn't clear from your code how you're going to use the output, so I'm not going to try and second-guess how best to present it (but I would expect that network ID and level on the same line would be a nice output — and it is doable).

Comment: yes, this is a better and simpler solution avoiding anything related to files.

Comment: yeah I think too. I specifically like the fact that I don't need intensive file I/O if I want this command to run every second or so.

Answer (score 4):

In general, you can accomplish this type of routing using `tee` and process substitution:

```
iwlist NIC scan | tee >( grep -i ESSID | awk '{print $1}' ) | grep -i level | awk '{print $3}'
```

but this is inferior in this situation for several reasons:

1. `grep` is superfluous, since `awk` can do the filtering itself
2. The two branches are similar enough to fold into a single `awk` command, as Jonathan Leffler points out.
3. The two output streams are merged together in a nondeterministic manner, so it may be difficult or impossible to determine which level corresponds to which ESSID. Storing the output of each branch in a file and later matching them line by line helps, but then this is not much better than asgs's solution.

But the technique of passing one command's output to two different pipelines without an explicit temporary file may be useful elsewhere; consider this answer just a demonstration.

Comment: +1: Your answer is very like what I started to write, complete with the list of the drawbacks.  Then I realized that it wasn't necessary if you simply use '`awk` as `grep`', and rewrote my answer top-to-bottom.